# Object not updating/not drawing at new position

Tags: c#, xna

I have 3 classes:
- Game1 (main class)
- Entity (base entity class)
- Player (player class, extends Entity class)

I draw the player class, but after that I can't seem to change the position of the player object.

```
public class Game1 : Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game
{
    GraphicsDeviceManager graphics;
    SpriteBatch spriteBatch;

    //Create a list with all the entities
    List<Entity> entityList = new List<Entity>();

    //Player
    Player player;

    public Game1()
    {
        graphics = new GraphicsDeviceManager(this);
        Content.RootDirectory = "Content";
    }

    protected override void Initialize()
    {
        // TODO: Add your initialization logic here

        base.Initialize();
    }

    protected override void LoadContent()
    {
        // Create a new SpriteBatch, which can be used to draw textures.
        spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch(GraphicsDevice);

        //Create player
        Texture2D playertexture = Content.Load<Texture2D>("player/player");
        Rectangle playerrectangle = new Rectangle(10, 10, playertexture.Width, playertexture.Height);

        player = new Player(playertexture, playerrectangle);

        entityList.Add(player);

    }

    protected override void UnloadContent()
    {
        // TODO: Unload any non ContentManager content here
    }

    protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        // Allows the game to exit
        if (Keyboard.GetState().IsKeyDown(Keys.Escape))
            this.Exit();

        //Update players and entities
        player.Update(graphics.GraphicsDevice);

        base.Update(gameTime);
    }


    protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.CornflowerBlue);

        spriteBatch.Begin();

        //Draw player
        player.Draw(spriteBatch);

        spriteBatch.End();

        base.Draw(gameTime);
    }
}

class Entity
{

    //Standard variables
    int health;
    int armor;
    float speed;
    float friction;

    //Get graphic and bounding box
    Texture2D texture;
    Rectangle rectangle;

    public Entity(Texture2D newTexture, Rectangle newRectangle){

        texture = newTexture;
        rectangle = newRectangle;

    }

    public void Update(GraphicsDevice graphics) {



    }

    public void Draw(SpriteBatch spriteBatch) {


    }

    /*
     * Modifiers for the variables
     */
    public void modifyHealth(int amount) { health = health + amount; }
    public void modifyArmor(int amount){ armor = armor + amount; }
    public void modifySpeed(float amount) { speed = speed + amount; }

    /*
     * Getters for variables
     */
    public int getHealth() { return health;  }
    public int getArmor() { return armor; }
    public float getSpeed() { return speed; }
    public float getFriction() { return friction; }

    /*
     * Setters for variables
     */
    public void setHealth(int amount) { health = amount; }
    public void setArmor(int amount) { armor = amount; }
    public void setSpeed(float amount) { speed = amount; }
    public void setFriction(float amount) { friction = amount; }

    /*
     * Functions
     */
    public void damage(int damage) {

        /*
         * Calculate health
         * 
         * Armor takes half the damage, if possible
         */
        if (damage / 2 >= armor) {
            damage = damage / 2;
            armor -= damage;
        } else if (armor > 0) {
            damage -= armor;
            armor = 0;
        }

        health -= damage;

        if(health <= 0){
            health = 0;
            //TODO Death
        }
    }
}

class Player : Entity
{

    //Create player
    Entity player;

    //Position and velocity
    Vector2 position;
    Vector2 velocity;

    //Texture and rectangle
    Texture2D texture;
    Rectangle rectangle;

    public Player(Texture2D newtexture, Rectangle newrectangle) : base(newtexture, newrectangle) {

        texture = newtexture;
        rectangle = newrectangle;

        //Set basic variables
        this.setHealth(100);
        this.setArmor(0);
        this.setSpeed(10);
        this.setFriction(1);

    }

    public void Update() {

        //Movement
        if(Keyboard.GetState().IsKeyDown(Keys.Right)){
            rectangle.X += 1;
        }

        rectangle.Y += 4;


    }

    public void Draw(SpriteBatch spriteBatch) {

        spriteBatch.Draw(texture, rectangle, Color.White);

    }
}
```

If there are also general mistakes I make, do point them out, I want to make everything as good as I can now that I'm still learning. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your calling   `public void Update(GraphicsDevice graphics)`

but the movement code is in `public void Update()`

What I suggest you do is this, use the [virtual and override](http://www.dotnetperls.com/override) keywords.

In your entity class it should look like this:

```
 public virtual void Update(GraphicsDevice graphics) {

    }
```

And in your player class

```
public override void Update(GraphicsDevice graphics) {
//ADD MOVEMENT CODE HERE
    }
```

Comment: Right. Because right now the call goes to the `Player`'s base class `Entity` which has no code in its `public void Update(GraphicsDevice graphics)` method.

Comment: Thanks! I'm very new to the graphics aspect of programming, so yeah. :)

Comment: By the way you can fill out your personal description page with info on your level of programming for people to know what kinds of mistakes to look out for, if you have any further questions on SE.